# Difference between ToA and TDoA

Tags: signals

I am a bit confused about the difference between Time of Arrival and Time difference of arrival.

I found this [website](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Time_difference_of_arrival) which explains the difference. But since English is not my first language I am not sure if I understood it correctly.

As I understood it, ToA: The device (for example) sends a signal with a time stamp. I know how fast a radio signal is and can therefore calculate the distance with the time of arrival on the base station and the time stamp in the transmission.

TDoA: The device sends a signal to multiple base stations. Those stations have a synchronized clock. Now the distance is calculated on the difference between the arrival time on both base stations.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

TDoA: The device (Tag) transmits in a regular interval (refresh rate) short blink message. Such a message is processed by ALL the Anchors in communication range. Regardless their synchronization status, the Anchors send all the timestamps to the RTLS Server through the Ethernet. There is only a single message from the tag comparing to TWR, saving the tag battery. More details on [TDoA methodology](https://www.sewio.net/uwb-technology/time-difference-of-arrival/).